# how to start a particular activity in android while starting the app

Tags: android, database

What I am doing is that if database has 0 rows then start `activity1` otherwise start `activity2`.

So how is this possible? I am getting error and application is crashing every time.
I have used if-else, but it's not working.
Please help.

This is the code:

```java
if (db.fetchnumber(1) == null) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
} else {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,activity2.class);    
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

`fetchnumber` method is:

```java
public String fetchnumber(long rowID) throws SQLException
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + PHONE_NUMBER + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_ROWID + " = 1 ;"

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, PHONE_NUMBER }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID ,null, 
            null,null,null,null);
    String str = null;
    if (csr != null)
    {  
        csr.moveToFirst();
    str = csr.getString(1);
    }

    return str;

}
```

Comment: if(db.fetchnumber(1) == null)
  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
  else
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
  startActivity(i);
  
  }

Comment: error is...:
application is crashing and further in logcat i have errors like null pointer exception and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps.

1) Create an Activity(register it in Manifest with.. set launcher and main tag in its manifest)

2) In step one you created a main activity now, Say Activity A

3) In A's `onCreate()` method fetch ur database methods to see of database has some values or not.

4) if db returns null in step 3 , you can start activity1 else u can start activity2.

to start an activity use `startActivity(intent)` method

to reading database rows you can see `cursor.getCount()` which returns number of rows in a table to which cursor is pointing.

your code should look like as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        DatabaseClass db = new DatabasClass(this);

        if(db.fetchDB() == null)
            StartActivity(intent1);
        else
            startActivity(intent2);


    }

}
```